# What are the alternative play to earn systems out there except NFT/Crypto?

Tags: monetization, real-money-transactions

I'm looking for play to earn system to use, The idea in itself seems neat until one realize that it's all about NFTs and Crypto, and I don't want any of that.

What are the alternative play to earn systems out there?
The game is supposed to be an RPG with multiple minigames in it, a roleplaying party game.

I need to know if ''play to earn'' is only limited to basically just selling nfts or fake currencies, be them in game currencies or crypto or if maybe there are other options.

Comment: Please explain the problem you are trying to solve, or the idea you are trying to realize, in the context of the game you are making. *Searching for definition of "play to earn" it appears to mean games where you can get cryptocurrency or NFTs. So, I'm guessing we are talking of something like a casino game. Is that what you want? However, I'm also aware of the unrealistic expectation that game related NFTs will have value or even usability after the game is defunct, and I don't know if that is something you are trying to tackle. Or do you mean something else? Please elaborate.*

Comment: By casino games I mean games where you buy some in-game premium currency, then you can expend it or perhaps earn more of it in game, and then you can exchange it back to real world money. There could be multiple in-game premium currencies. The way to earn more may involve buying items with it. It does not have to be a classic casino game (e.g. poker). - By the way, due to data protection laws, many video games companies must give you a copy of your in-game data upon request. If they a digital certificate on that, it will serve as proof of what you had in the game even after it is defunct.

Comment: @Theraot I want nothing to do with casinos NFTs or crypto

Comment: @Theaot I think your mention of casino games is concise and convincing proof that play to earn has existed long before cryptocurrencies and can be implemented through more conventional means. As usual, what crypto is providing here is not the enabling tech, but obfuscation to make an end run around regulations that normally apply to gambling or other financial transactions, particularly those that could be used for money laundering (at least in the short term, until the laws catch up to the new systems). Want to write up your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

**Alternatives to "play to earn"**

There are plenty of monetization systems. They include:

- Selling licenses to the game  (i.e. selling digital copies).
- Selling time limited subscriptions (either to access parts of the game, or access the game at all).
- And selling items in the game (i.e. micro-transactions).

*This is not an exhaustive list.*

---

"Play to earn" is a very new terminology. Before I get into what it means, I want to point out that it sounds like an alternative to:

- "pay to play": Games supported by selling licenses.
- "pay to win": Microtransactions supported games where you can pay to be reduce the difficulty. It could be, for example, by making the player more effective, or outright skipping content.
- "free to play": Games where there is no entry fee. They could be games supported by microtransactions or ad revenue or something else.

In fact, I would argue that whoever came up with the term "play to earn" made it sound like those terms on purpose.

---

**What is "play to earn" and what does it promise?**

Is there some promise made by "play to earn", which you wish to fulfill? (without blockchains, cryptocurrencies and NFTs). I don't know. So beyond what "play to earn" means, I'll try to cover other related promises.

So, what "play to earn" says on the tin is that you will play the game and earn things.

The promise of being able to play and earn things in a game is nothing new. Plenty of game have mechanics in which you earn trophies or titles, or you buy things in the game. Thus, that cannot be what they mean by "play to earn".

Instead, "play to earn" means that:

- There will be an entry fee   (paid in a crypto-currency).
- Then in the game you will be able to earn assets  (in the form of NFTs).
- And you will be able to exchange those assets for money outside the game (again as the crypto-currency).

What remains if we remove the crypto-currencies and NFTs from "play to earn"? You pay an entry fee (in real money) to play, and you will play the game, hoping to earn more than your entry fee, and cash out.

That is the same promise that casinos make. In fact, I would argue casinos are "play to earn". Except without the use of blockchains. In fact, they do have their custom currency in the form of casino chips/tokens.

You need to consider that having a cash out option in your game have legal implications. In fact, you will have similar - if not the same - legal liabilities as game shows, casinos, and lotteries.

---

There is also the unrealistic promise that the things you earn will keep their value. Even after the game or the game company is defunct. This is unrealistic because without the game the assets are useless and thus won't keep value.

Due to data protection laws, video games companies must give you a copy of your in-game data upon request. So the information about what you owned in the game is not lost when the game or game company is defunct.

If you add a digital certificate to that, it would be possible to verify its authenticity. Even the game company is defunct.

Yet digital certificates are not what you would call an NFT. They are not on a blockchain. In fact, it has a central authority: your game servers. People cannot trade or transfer them without your game server. Since there is a central authority, you can do something about any scammers.

I have also seen another related promise: that you will be able to bring items you got in a game into other games. That is unrealistic because games are not homogeneous, nor are game engines. But, If a game can honor NFTs from another game, a game can honor digital certificates from another game. Which does not need a blockchain or anything like that.

---

By the way, in-game currencies have been around for much longer than crypto-currencies. You kill some monster, you earn some "gold", you use it to buy from an NPC, that is an in-game currency.

The same goes for premium (i.e. paid with real money) in-game currencies. And I'd argue they are not a bad thing. *Yes, loot boxes, fear of missing out, and other predatory strategies are bad. But a premium in-game currency does not imply any of that.*

---

*Addendum:*

There is another promise these games make that I had skipped over: That the NFTs will be unique. On one hand, unique drops aren't new. See for example equipment in Diablo. Or for a more recent reference see weapons in Borderlands. Or riven mods in Warframe. Also, every Pokémon has unique hidden stats. On the other hand, an unique NFT does not mean an unique item in game. There could be multiple unique NFTs that all refer to identical things in the game.

Another thing I want to mention is that NFTs have a minting cost. And if this cost is not transferred to the player directly, it is being paid from the pool of cryptocurrency from the entry fees, or people buying premium currency in the game (which they may do as secondary NFTs). In other words, the players are paying for the NFTs with extra steps. Which is why the promises are mostly about the value *outside* of the game.

---

**On the monetization for your game**

> The game is supposed to be an RPG with multiple minigames in it, a roleplaying party game.

You can do this with monetization options that do not depend on in-game currencies. For example it could be a subscription, or it could be ad supported. Or the game could be free to play, with microtransaction paid on a premium in-game currency. *Which does not imply blockchain, or crypto-currency or NFTs.*

Be aware that running central servers has a cost, and you would need to recoup it.

With the words "party" and "minigame" I'm imagining something like Mario Party, which would not have to be an MMO. If that is the case, you could build it without a central server.

Instead of a central server, you could do couch multiplayer, or over LAN. Or you could take advantage of third party infrastructure available at no cost. For example run it over Discord servers, or with WebRTC. That way, the game can avoid the server cost. Which means you don't need as aggressive monetization.